# A real life scenario where hibernate load is used not get

Tags: hibernate

I know the differences between `get` and `load` methods in hibernate. But can't understand the real life scenario where I can use load method instead of get method.

Please give a real life scenario where hibernate load method is used and not the get method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to set a product's category. So you have a page listing the categories, allowing to select one, and posting the form.

Posting the form consists in calling the following method:

```
public void setProductCategory(Long productId, Long categoryId)
```

This method must get the product to modify it, and get a reference to the category, in order to be able to call

```
product.setCategory(category);
```

But do you really need to load the data of the category to do that? You already have its ID, and that should be sufficient to get a reference to the corresponding category, without actually getting all the data of the category from te database. After all, all Hibernate has to do is to populate the category_id column of the product row in the database, and you already know the ID of the category, so loading the rest of the category data is unnecessary.

This is where `load()` is handy: it let's you get a reference to a persistent object without actually loading the data of the object:

```
Product product = (Product) session.get(Product.class, productId);
Category category = (Category) session.load(Category.class, categoryId);
product.setCategory(category);
```